# Setting up th:field attribute in thymeleaf is replacing name attribute

Tags: spring-boot, radio-button, thymeleaf

I have a form where I need to show many questions and multiple answers. I am using spring boot with Thymeleaf and looping a list that displays a label for the question and radio button for multiple choices. When I set the: field attribute to capture the user input it replaces the name attribute of all the radio buttons. In this case, I can select only one radio button for all the questions. I replicated that it looks like a bug in thymeleaf library.  Can someone suggest facing the same thing?

I have created a sample application. Repo is created on github.

https://github.com/ashokruhela/thymeleaf-radio.git

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http:www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>contest questions</h1>
    <form action="@{/result}" th:object="${contest}">
        <div th:each="ques,qs: ${contest.questions}">
            <label th:text="${ques.title}"></label>
            <div th:each="option,os:${ques.options}">
                <input type="radio"
                       th:field="*{ques.answer}"
                       th:name="${'question'+qs.count}"
                       th:id="${'Q'+qs.count+'opt'+os.count}"
                       th:value="${option.descpription}" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Contest

```
package com.ak.learning.hibernatemapping;
import java.util.List;

public class Contest {
    String name;
    List<ContestQuestion> questions;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<ContestQuestion> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<ContestQuestion> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
}
```

Question

```
package com.ak.learning.hibernatemapping;
import java.util.List;

public class ContestQuestion {
    String title;
    String answer;

    List<QuestionOption> options;

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<QuestionOption> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(List<QuestionOption> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}
```

Options

```
package com.ak.learning.hibernatemapping;

public class QuestionOption {
    String description;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

controller

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class ContestController {
    @GetMapping("/contest")
    public String contest(Model model){

        Contest contest = new Contest();
        //adding the questions is ommitted.....
        model.addAttribute("contest", contest);
        return "contest";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244936/bind-a-list-of-radio-buttons-with-spring-and-thymeleaf ?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if you need it yet but I struggle with the exact problem for two days, so I am going to post what I discovered since it can help someone else.

First, th:field overrides name and id values. So, to make each group of questions in separate radio attribute name, you need two iterations: one for question, and one for each option. The big problem here is how to bind the chosen option to the th:field.

You need to know that this field will receive the chosen "value" attribute in a String format, so what I did here is adding a "String chosenOption" attribute to my question model. In the end, in my case, I had a html like this:

```
<fieldset th:each="question, count: ${questions.questions}">
                
                <label th:text="${question.text}"></label>
                
                <ul >
                    <li th:each="option : ${question.options}">
                        
                        <input th:value="${option.title}" th:field="*{questionObject[__${count.index}__].optionChosen}" type="radio"/>
                        <label th:text="${option.text}"></label> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
            </fieldset>
```

It is important to consider here two things: the counter to iterate over the questionObject list of options so that Spring can bind the answers in a list properly. I created a title attribute for the Question and Option models so that it is easier to put then into the input attributes

PS: I translated the code to english, so maybe some elements can be with wrong name, but the important idea is how to make the iterations and the bind.

Answer (score -2):

Just Add This In Your HTML Tag Of Thymeleaf Page

```
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
```

And You Are Good to Go.

Comment: Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . And use/trust the preview, then you do not need to experiment with multiple publishing...

Comment: if you read the code that the OP provided, then you would see that the OP already using that.

Comment: Don't start every word with a capital letter. In English, a capital letter is used for the first word of a sentence and for all proper nouns.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).